# Twitter timeline loading in Vue mounted hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, twitter

I'm having problems with loading the twitter timeline in a Vue app. The timeline loads properly during the initial page access, but after using the navigation or refreshing the page, the twitter timeline no longer appears.

I'm trying to load widgets.js file through the mounted function:

```
mounted: function () {
//TWITTER 
window.twttr = (function (d,s,id) {
var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function(f){ t._e.push(f) } });
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
twttr.widgets.load();
}
```

I'm using `twttr.widgets.load();` in order to dynamically load the widget according to this doc: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/javascript-api/guides/scripting-loading-and-initialization.

Worth to note that I'm receiving the following error in a console, which basically means that at the time of calling `twttr.widgets.load();` the widgets.js file is not available:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined"
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `load()` in `ready()` function

```
twttr.ready(() => twttr.widgets.load());
```

Comment: Thanks. How this would look like in the code? Should I just extend the Twitter Timeline Script in the mounted hook?